# Android display AlertDialog on receiving broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I want to show display an AlertDialog after I receive a broadcast receiver when the airplane is toggled on or off. This has been possible by displaying a transparent activity which then displays my dialog. However, I simply want an alertDialog without any activity(similar to TrueCaller's dialog or the likes). What is the best approach to accomplish this.

DataReceiver.class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        mainIntent.putExtra("value","Airplane mode toggled");
     context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity.class));

        Toast.makeText(context, "Airplane mode toggled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);Color.parseColor("#01000000")));

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Airplane mode Toggled");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Works");
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".DataReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: what is your target SDK...from API 26 you may not do that...the broadcast of AIRPLANE_MODE is not triggered if your receiver is declared in manifest. Read: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: Target SDK 26. However, irregardless of the receiver, how can I achieve the desired output? Thanks in advance

Comment: Only way i can think off but may not really be the right fix for your usecase.  Run a jobservice frequently and check if the aeroplane mode is enabled. If its enabled then create a notification saying "Aeroplane enabled" and on click of that take to your app. There is another way which is to run a foregroundservice but thats not totally recommended and i am not proposing that as well :)